# bluebird with mongoose, TypeError: .create(...).then(...).nodeify is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, bluebird

I'm trying to use bluebird in mongoose. But meet some questions:

I write some test code of bluebird and not used mongoose in it. Just like this:

`A().then().error().catch().nodeify() ....`

And it works.

But when I used mongoose operations, then error occurs.
Just a demo code like this:
`Username.create().then().nodeify() ...`

And TypeError: .create().then().nodeify is not a function.

(And I have tried asCallback, doesn't work either. The same error)

If use error() in it, it also have the same error:

`Username.create().then().error().nodeify() ...`

`TypeError: .create().then().error is not a function`

(username is a mongoose model)

I'm sure that bluebird is in it.

`var mongoose = require('mongoose');`
`var P = mongoose.promise = require('bluebird');`

so where is the problem ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's `mongoose.Promise = require('bluebird');`, not `mongoose.promise`.